# How to calculate detection_score for OpenCV's face detector?

Tags: opencv, face-detection, viola-jones

I want to use [FDDB](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/fddb/) to evaluate some face detectors including OpenCV. But FDDB's detection output file requires:

```
<left_x top_y width height detection_score>
```

It include a `detection_score` part. But the opencv's detector have no output like this. How to output this?

Comment: this [fddb](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/fddb/) ? also please note, that a more modern opencv version also comes with pretrained lbp cascades, so it's not limited to the viola-jones idea.

Comment: yes. Even the lbp cascades, it should output the detection score for fddb testing.

Comment: have not tried (so, not an answer), but afaik, you can use [this detectMultiScale overload](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/objdetect/include/opencv2/objdetect.hpp#L160) , the levelWeights should be proportional to a score

Comment: Thanks, berak! I'll try that. I get a reference from Google which uses the number of rectangles: http://haoxiang.org/2013/11/opencv-detectmultiscale-output-detection-score/. does it make scene?.

Comment: @HoneyTidy The detection score computed in the blog post mentioned can be easily computed using new OpenCv api which returns number of faces. You can also set minNeighbors to zero and then group the rectangles using groupRectangles method of Opencv. However, this approach will be incorrect.

Comment: @HoneyTidy Viola jones based classifier moves a window over the whole image to check for faces. In OpenCv, ystep variable is used to define the step between the window. Now, if a face in image is of size 100X100, then number of detection will be 4 times larger if the size of face is 50x50. For large faces(500x500), I would get value of 1000 but for small areas(50x50), I would get value like 10. Please answer this question if you seemed to have gone with some better approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From their FAQ (http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/fddb/faq.html)

They define the detection score for a candidate window as:

K*stage_when_rejected + stage_sum_for_stage_when_rejected. 
(Choosing K as a large value e.g., 1000)

to ensure that windows rejected at stage i have higher score than those rejected at stage i-1